# Google Chrome Devtools cannot highlight elements in IFrame over certain height

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Can anyone help here, i'm wondering if this is actually a bug or expected behaviour?

Chrome Dev Tools seems to not be allowing hovering elements and highlighting of them in Iframes over a certain height.

For example, look here:

http://csreis.github.io/tests/cross-site-iframe-simple.html

now if you set the iframe height to 3000px, and then go and try to inspect the 'Cross the bridge' button. It does not highlight or allow you to select anything below the container you can see about half way down the picture.

I am getting this same behaviour on a different project I am working on, where the highlighting is not working in dev tools in an iframe.

Is anyone else getting this behaviour? I am using Chrome 88.0.4324.190 and am seeing this behaviour on other machines too. I am *not* getting this behaviour using Firefox which allows me to highlight all elements in iframes. I'm stumped on this one.

Thanks.

[image: dev tools]

Comment: Can anyone confirm that they are even having this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same issue and I feel like I'm debugging with a blindfold on.

Comment: Same. Has anyone reported this bug? I think this worked correctly before. Also I'm using Linux, does it happen in other operating systems?

Comment: I've reported this issue here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1219647

Comment: @Sentero-esp12 yes, issue occurs for me on Windows machine(s).